# mssql-cli connect to local server server container error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: sql-server, centos, entity-framework-core, sql-server-linux

I just run sql server via docker on CentOS 7

```
sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Admin@2019'  -p 1433:1433 --name sql2017  -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

then, I try to connect via mssql-cli got error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

Please note that when try to use `sqlcmd`, it works fine:

```
./sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Admin@2019'
```

Also I have same issue when use in ASP.NET EF Core

Answer (score 0):

I found [Configure CSF](https://kb.yourwebhoster.eu/knowledge-base/how-to-use-docker-with-portainer-and-directadmin-without-ssh-access/) article and just configure iptables/csf

My Server config: CentOS + DirectAdmin + Docker